# Memory leaks when unarchiving

Tags: objective-c, ipad, memory-leaks, nsarray, nskeyedarchiver

I would appreciate some support regarding a memory leak I have.

I have data in an array that I have archived with NSKeyedArchiver. I later on un-archive it. From a functional point of view it is working well, but when I run Instruments for Memory Leaks I get memory leaks when un-archiving.

This is the code:

```
NSArray *arrayToLoad = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path]]; 

ballPath = [arrayToLoad copy];

[arrayToLoad release];
```

Where ballPath is an NSArray.

Instruments indicates that 100% of the leak is related to the first line in the code above. I am clearly missing something but am not able to find out what. I think that [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path] is autoreleased and the arrayToLoad is released, so I'm lost.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Have you released the `ballPath`, when you done using it?

Comment: what do you do with ballPath - it's retain count should be 1 at the end of that code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I am only reading values in ballPath after it is set with the copy of arrayToLoad. Still have not figured out why I have a memory leak, but the below code works, even if I'm not in any way proud of it:

```
if ([ballPath retainCount] > 0) {
    [ballPath release];
}

NSArray *arrayToLoad = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path]]; 

ballPath = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayToLoad];

[arrayToLoad release];
```